# Compromised DigitalOcean droplet routing strange traffic

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, security

I have a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 16.04 droplet with pre-installed Wordpress. It has SSH login 
enabled with root and password login disabled. UFW is enabled.

Not a security expert and only a novice webdev but it seems it has been compromised.

I think this occured because I disabled 'strict SQL mode' as per this tutorial:
https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-disable-strict-mode-in-mysql-5-7.html

I had a second Wordpress install to install on the server and could only do it with 
strict mode disabled. I didn't re-enable it once I completed the install.

Here is an excerpt from the Apache2 error.log file:

```
[Mon Dec 05 10:32:51.819437 2016] [:error] [pid 15466] [client 172.68.10.110:26708] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1868
[Mon Dec 05 10:32:51.821173 2016] [:error] [pid 15466] [client 172.68.10.110:26708] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in /var/www/html/wp$
[Mon Dec 05 10:32:51.819142 2016] [:error] [pid 4570] [client 66.249.79.102:64614] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/html/wp-include$
[Mon Dec 05 10:32:51.821877 2016] [:error] [pid 4570] [client 66.249.79.102:64614] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in /var/www/html/wp-$
[Mon Dec 05 10:32:51.819998 2016] [:error] [pid 3981] [client 173.245.55.78:35305] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/html/wp-include$
[Mon Dec 05 10:32:51.822283 2016] [:error] [pid 3981] [client 173.245.55.78:35305] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in /var/www/html/wp-$
[Mon Dec 05 15:12:58.198942 2016] [core:error] [pid 17194] (36)File name too long: [client 66.249.79.104:58168] AH00036: access to /read-online-psychedelic-research-in$
[Mon Dec 05 23:02:30.550613 2016] [core:error] [pid 20194] (36)File name too long: [client 66.249.79.98:51473] AH00036: access to /read-online-peoples-temple-including$
[Tue Dec 06 04:15:03.795417 2016] [core:error] [pid 21882] (36)File name too long: [client 66.249.79.98:53902] AH00036: access to /novels-by-tad-williams-including-the$
[Tue Dec 06 07:47:20.068192 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1475] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 06 07:47:21.097262 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23589] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 06 07:47:21.097393 2016] [core:notice] [pid 23589] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Dec 06 07:54:16.190667 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23589] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 06 07:54:32.918723 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1525] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 06 07:54:32.934492 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1525] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Dec 06 07:55:51.504685 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1525] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Dec 06 07:55:52.592154 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1906] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 06 07:55:52.592279 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1906] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Dec 06 08:45:58.655029 2016] [core:error] [pid 2052] (36)File name too long: [client 66.249.79.79:42704] AH00036: access to /read-online-encyclopedia-of-christmas$
```

And here is an excerpt from the Apache2 access.log file:

```
130.193.51.38 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:55 +0000] "GET /file-archive-1692.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 517 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
66.249.79.98 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:55 +0000] "GET /file-archive-1575.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 516 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.htm$
172.68.11.121 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:56 +0000] "GET /steps-for-astaire-by-nigel-roberts.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 537 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yand$
66.249.79.98 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:56 +0000] "GET /christian-prayer-liturgy-of-the-hours-black-leather.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 550 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2$
66.249.79.122 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:56 +0000] "GET /colonel-roosevelt.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.ht$
66.249.79.98 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:57 +0000] "GET /definitive-bob-dylan-songbook-music-sales-america.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1$
172.68.11.131 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:57 +0000] "GET /doris-force-at-locked-gates-gytcjx.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 537 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yand$
66.249.79.79 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:57 +0000] "GET /read-online-le-belv-d-re-du-diable-by-rosemary-carter.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot$
66.249.79.98 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:58 +0000] "GET /read-online-furball-and-feathers-by-sean-sweeney.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 547 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;$
172.68.11.121 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:58 +0000] "GET /until-it-breaks-by-suggestivescribe.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 538 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yan$
66.249.79.98 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:58 +0000] "GET /the-knights-templars-the-key-of-solomon-the-king.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 547 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;$
66.249.79.81 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:59 +0000] "GET /file-archive-845.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html$
66.249.79.98 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:59 +0000] "GET /guide-to-old-radios-pointers-pictures-and-prices.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 547 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;$
172.68.11.134 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:59 +0000] "GET /the-puppet-boy-of-warsaw-eva-weaver.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 538 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yan$
66.249.79.98 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:21:59 +0000] "GET /bon-voyage-level-2-student-edition-glencoe-french.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1$
66.249.79.102 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:22:00 +0000] "GET /read-online-the-seal-s-surprise-baby-by-amy-j-fetzer.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 552 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot$
162.158.91.152 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:22:00 +0000] "GET /my-philosophy-for-successful-living.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 538 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://ya$
66.249.79.106 - - [05/Dec/2016:08:22:00 +0000] "GET /read-online-time-enough-for-drums-by-ann-rinaldi.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1$
```

I was using nano to grab these so they got partially cutoff.

As you can see my server is making all these strange GET requests, it looks like torrent traffic or something.

172.68.10.110 and 172.68.11.121 are Russian IPs.

Is this just a consequence of disabling SQL's strict mode? Any advice?

Comment: These are not request made by your server, but requests made to your server. There

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal server behavior and nothing of particular concern.

The reason that you are seeing requests for some odd URLs may be that the IP address you were assigned from DigitalOcean was previously used to host another website -- its something that is very common and is nothing to worry about.

Comment: I had actually read that but it seemed too simple, but thank you! Now I know.